# Wordpress: Page use Category Template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a 'Portfolio' page.  Is it possible to make this use the standard Category template? (category.php)

If not, how about the opposite?  Can I make a custom template (which the Portfolio page will use) and make all Category requests go there as well?

To clarify:  The Portfolio page is displaying the same thing as the Category page.  But it needs to be under the heading of Portfolio. They will both display Categories.  Is there some way to combine these but keep the 'Portfolio' page involved?

Comment: A page and a category template are different things, aren't they? Showing different kinds of stuff in different kinds of loops? I don't see how they could be fused together in a sensible way. Why not just copy them over?

Comment: I'm not actually display page content on the Portfolio page.  It's just a nav menu item essentially.  I was just hoping there was a way to redirect both the categories and the page to a custom template or something

Comment: What *are* you displaying on the portfolio page then? If it's just a menu item, I think you should be able to just make it point to the right category. It's definitely possible to have two menu items pointing at the same place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect your portfolio page to a specific category (as you mentioned in your comment above) then you can simply add a hook in your functions.php like

```
function redirect_to_category()
{
    //I assumed that your page slug is portfolio,id or page title can be used too
    if(is_page('portfolio'))
    {
        $page_url = "your category url"; //i.e. http://yourdomain/category/anitem
        wp_redirect($page_url);  // you can also redirect to any page/category   
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_to_category');
```

If you paste this code in your functions.php, this will cause your user to redirect to the given category (in $page_url variable) page according to your is_page return value. For more about custom template visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use custom template. And assign that template to page of portfolio.

And display the category post loop in that template.

Url create template :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Using query post loop you can display display post from that portfolio category.

Url :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts